# Link to another file in chrome extension

Tags: google-chrome

I want to have a link in the popup.html file for my extension that loads another file (which will be included with the extension) how can I do this? or will I need to keep it in the same page?

I tried using this code:

```
<a href="/mail.html">
    <img id="newmail_icon" src="" width="16" height="16" />
    <span id="newmail">loading</span><br />
</a>
```

But when I click the link nothing happens.

I just found out that adding `target="_blank"` to the link will make it work and open in a new tab, but I can't get it to open in the popup. I have tried `target="_self"` but it didn't do anything.

Answer (score 3):

The API you are looking for is [chrome.extension.getURL](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/extension#method-getURL).

Comment: Deprecated since Chrome 58. Please use [runtime.getURL](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/runtime#method-getURL)

Answer (score 0):

You can reference the file /my_new_file.html

Where my_new_file is in the root of your directory.

Comment: I tried that before I posted the question but when I click the link nothing happens.

Comment: Yeah sorry, I was doing this in another page (not the popup) and it worked. You could create an iframe for your popup. Not ideal but might solve your problem.